# Get all the rows that are having one of the specified value in their column in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the database table like below.

```
    Schema::create('x_poll_questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('question');
            $table->text('batch_ids');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have data like,

```
1 |  test question 1 | ["1","4","2"]
2 |  test question 2 | ["1","5","3"]
3 |  test question 3 | ["1"]
4 |  test question 4 | ["3", "2"]
```

In the `batch_ids` column I have value like `["1","4","2"]`. Which is json decoded value of php array.

Now, How can I write the query that check if specified values(example 1,2) are present in the batch_ids column. If yes then return the row.

Need output as

```
1 |  test question 1 | ["1","4","2"]
4 |  test question 4 | ["3", "2"]
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Adding following function in poll model worked for me.

````
    public function scopeFilterByBatchIds($q, $batchIds)
    {
        if ($batchIds) {
            $batches = explode(',', $batchIds);

            foreach ($batches as $batchId) {
                $q->where('batch_ids', 'like', '%"' . $batchId . '"%');
            }
        }

        return $q;
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for DB Query WhereIn, you'll need to adjust accordingly

```
$filter_apostrophe = str_replace('"','', $value);
$separate_the_value = explode(',', $filter_apostrophe);

$data = DB::table('x_poll_questions')
      ->where('batch_ids','like','%'."".$separate_the_value."".'%') //Filter "" or not
      ->get()
```

What're the input format in search field

Comment: This is more like checks for all the values. I need either of the value is present then also should get the result.

Comment: @NiteshKesarkar What are the input. I've updated the code.

Comment: Yes Now worked for me. I have updated the question with the answer that I have used.